# Detecting frequency of a training set

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, frequency

I am trying to detect the frequency of the x-axis which is referred to (m) training set in my LSTM model

```
r,time, x, y, z, m, s,l = np.loadtxt('FINALkneeTRAIN.txt', delimiter = ',',
                                     unpack = True)
spectrum = fft.fft(m)
freq = fft.fftfreq(len(spectrum))
plt(freq, abs(spectrum))
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
plt(freq, abs(spectrum))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide some more information on your code. But I assume that this line is written somewhere:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

In this case, when you write `plt(freq, abs(spectrum))` you are referring to the module `plt` instead of a plotting function. If you do have the above line you probably want

```
plt.plot(freq, abs(spectrum))
```

In addition, you may find this numpy docpage useful

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me